# Codeigniter filter by category id for product table

Tags: php, filter, categories, codeigniter-3

I have this code which pulls out all the values from a table in my database and it works fine however, I don't want all the the products showing. I want to filter by `category_id`. The name of the table is called `products`. Here is the view file that shows all the products:

```html
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
 <div class="col-md-4 game">
  <div class="game-price"><?php echo $product->price; ?></div>
   <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/details/<?php echo $product->id; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/products/<?php echo $product->image; ?>" />
   </a>
   <div class="game-title">
    <?php echo $product->title; ?>
   </div>
   <div class="game-add">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/add">
       QTY: <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="1" /><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product->price; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $product->title; ?>" />
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
      </form>
   </div>
 </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is a screenshot of my table:
[Database Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBGhbPaJU_jRUZxemk3TGVqams)

How can I edit the code above so that it displays results for a specific category?

Here is my controller:

```html
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller{
 public function index(){
  //Get All Products
  $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products();

  //Load View
  $data['main_content'] = 'products';
  $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
 }

 public function details($id){
  //Get Product Details
  $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($id);

  //Load View
  $data['main_content'] = 'details';
  $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
 }

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->model('Search_model');
    }

    public function execute_search()
    {
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->Search_model->get_results($search_term);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->load->view('products',$data);
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```html
<?php
class Product_model extends CI_Model{
 /*
  * Get All Products
  */
  public function get_products(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('products');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
  }
  
  /*
   * Get Single Product
   */
   public function get_product_details($id){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('products');
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->row();
   }
   
   /*
    * Get Categories
    */
    public function get_categories(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('categories');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
    }
    
    /*
  * Get Most Popular Products
 */
 public function get_popular(){
  $this->db->select('P.*, COUNT(O.product_id) as total');
  $this->db->from('orders AS O');
  $this->db->join('products AS P', 'O.product_id = P.id', 'INNER');
  $this->db->group_by('O.product_id');
  $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
 
 /*
  * Add Order To Database
  */
  public function add_order($order_data){
  $insert = $this->db->insert('orders', $order_data);
        return $insert;
 }
}
```

This is the part that actually gets the products in my model and the part I think I have to edit:

```html
public function get_products(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('products');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

Comment: Show controller (and eventually model) code where you are querying DB.

Comment: I've added the controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

Pass one optional parameter to

```
public function index($category_id = false){
```

then same parameter pass to model's method

```
$data['products'] = $this->Product_model->get_products($category_id);
```

In model, you would make an check if id is valid value (i.e. positive int and then query DB with that clause, otherwise query them all)

```
public function get_products($category_id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');

    if ((int)$category_id > 0) {
        $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
 }
```

Something like this, but you should make some check for case when integer is passed but that cat id doesn't exist.

Comment: Let's say the caregory_id I want to use is "1" where would I input this?

Comment: How do you get products/index for now: from menu link or something similar?

Comment: The view I posted just draws the data directly from the database based on the controller and model using `<?php echo $product->title; ?>` for example. This one draws the title.

Comment: Make dropdown list somewhere on page and pass value selected through form to same url. Make if else block whether checking if there is an argument in method and serve data accordingly.